# handling archives in php

Tags: php, compression, inflate

I'm working on a distributable framework for websites (a kind of watered-down CMS) that has a module system for adding plugins. I'm going to use uploaded archives to install these modules, and I would like to allow zip, bzip, gzip, rar and tar to be used. I've done a bit of googling and know that some of those file types can be handled by the zlib extension or ZipArchive, however, I am unclear if either of those packages support the unpacking of those allowed filetypes. I've also looked into some 3rd party classes for handling archives (mainly pclzip), but most were released years ago with no recent updates. I'm not sure if there might be differences in how things should be handled now and how those packages worked. If anyone could shed a little more light upon the subject, I would be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

It would be tough to find libraries for all of those.  The easiest thing would be to use `system()` to run the relevant utility to extract the provided file type.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they do and for all the mentioned archive types exist extensions (see: http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php). For massive decompression operations using the binary tools, as Mark described, might be faster - not benchmarked, though.

Here an example on how to use ZipArchive, see docs for the others:

```
$z = new \ZipArchive();
if ($z->open("/some/path/the.zip") === true) {

    // extract all
    $z->extractTo("/some/path/output/folder");

    // extract by rel path
    if (($c = $z->getFromName("some/file/in/zip.txt")) !== false) {
        file_put_contents("/tmp/my-file.txt", $c);
    }

    // iterate all, print index: name
    for ($i = 0; $i < $z->numFiles; $i++) {
        $info = $z->statIndex($i);
        echo "File #$i: ". $info['name']. ' ('. $info['size']. " size)\n";
    }
    $z->close();
}
```

A bit annoying are the different interfaces. You might want to use a wrapper, there are a couple: https://packagist.org/search/?q=archive